# Avoid typeahead.js remote if regex matches

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, bloodhound

how do I avoid a server request in typeahead.js if certain regex matches?
I dont't want to start a suggestion if numbers are typed in but letters should start the ajax request.

Is this possible in typeahead.js or bloodhound?

I still have version 0.10.5 as an update would affect in too many places.

best regards
Eike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself:
Just return false in beforeSend.

```
engine = new Bloodhound({
   ajax: {
       url: "example.com",
       beforeSend: function() {
           return null === $(<selector>).typeahead("val").match(/regexIdontWant/);
       }
   }
});
```